# WildFly JMS topic consumer receives null value

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-artemis

I am using WildFly 19 and a JMS topic application. After running this program it returns a `null` value.

```java
try {
    final Properties env = new Properties();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "jmsuser");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Password1!");
    namingContext = new InitialContext(env);

    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
    Destination destination = (Destination) namingContext .lookup("jms/topic/myTopic");
    context = connectionFactory.createContext("jmsuser", "Password1!");
    context.createProducer().send(destination, "mymeninsgh city topic !");
    System.out.println("Sent message successuflly ");

    JMSConsumer consumer = context.createConsumer(destination);
    String text = consumer.receiveBody(String.class, 5000);
    System.out.println("Received message with content " + text);

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    throw e;
} finally {
    if (namingContext != null) {
        namingContext.close();
    }
    if (context != null) {
        context.close();
    }
}
```

WildFly topic configuration is :

[image]

After run this program it gives bellow error:

```
Sent message successuflly 
Received message with content null
```

How can solve this error (`null`)? How can I get actual value instead of `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the **expected behavior** since you're sending the message to a JMS topic before creating a consumer. This is because JMS topics follow publish/subscribe semantics which dictate that messages sent before any subscriptions are created get discarded.

You should either:

- Create your consumer first and *then* send the message.
- Send the message to a JMS *queue*.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem with using JMS topic (wildfy ). In this case I have to JMS topic , so i am doing  publish/subscribe semantics .

```
   namingContext = new InitialContext(env);
   ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)    namingContext.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
            Topic topic = (Topic)  namingContext.lookup("jms/topic/myTopic");
            context = connectionFactory.createContext("murad", "Murad@1234");
            JMSConsumer consumer = context.createSharedConsumer(topic, "fardeen");
        
            System.out.println("Waiting for messages on topic");
            TextListener listener = new TextListener();
            consumer.setMessageListener(listener);
```

Comment: it is  typo mistake here .